# UILabel change position in center of the screen for iOS in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilabel

I want to change the label position from the top of the screen to a center of the screen programmatically when I press a button.

How do I achieve that?

My Code so far:

```
outputMessageLabel.Frame = new CGRect(outputMessageLabel.Bounds.X, 
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height / 2, outputMessageLabel.Bounds.Width, 
outputMessageLabel.Bounds.Height);
```

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried please?

Comment: @CatalinHalic next time, put the code into the question directly. Brendon was nice enough to do it for you... However, dont count on that! Always provide an [mcve] to make it easier for us helping YOU!

Comment: @Mafii thank you for advice, it is my first question in this community, for next questions I will be more carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this task:

1. You can set two labels, one at top of screen and second at center. Hide the center one. On the action of the button, hide the top one and unhide the middle one (eg. `mylabel.hidden = False`).
2. Other thing you can do is create the label programmatically in `viewdidload` or `viewwillappear` by putting:

   ```
   if (flag == 0){
       label location at top
   } else {
      label location at middle
   }
   ```

And on the button click, call your method `viewdidload` / `viewwillappear` through `NSPostNotification`.

There is third way also:
3. On click of the button just change the offsets of the button.

Comment: Thank you Garry, I will use your first suggestion.